# Delphi compiler directive for shortstrings not working?

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-xe2, compiler-directives

I'm trying to port a project from Delphi 4 to Delphi XE2. I have a requirement to use `shortstring` in the project. According to the Delphi Help, $H- should make the compiler use shortstrings for the `string` type. I've used this directive but I don't see any difference. I've written a small test program:

```
program Stringtest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}
{$H- }
uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
 str : string;
 short : shortstring;
begin
  try
    str := 'testing';
    short := 'testing';
    Writeln('str ' +Format('%d', [sizeOf(str)]) );
    Writeln('short  ' +Format('%d', [sizeOf(short)])  );
    Readln; 
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

In my opinion the output should be the same for both `str` and `short` because the compiler should treat both as a `shortstring`. But the size is 4 for `str` and 256 for `short`. Is there any other way to have the compiler treat `string` as `shortstring` or is the only solution to replace all occurences of  `string` with `shortstring` in the source code?

Comment: `$H-` is legacy, provided only for backward compatibility. There is no way to force the Delphi XE2 (or any version of Delphi's compiler from D2009 and higher) to not use Unicode as the default string type. You'll need to explicitly change all of your string references to shortstring (or better yet, fix your code to not require them).

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for your answer. That confirms my suspicions. In the [help section](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/String_Types) for String Type of Delphi XE 2, it is written that the $H- directive could be used for that purpose. But I guess that is outdated then.

Comment: it's there just to prevent old code from breaking when compiled. There was a bit of an uproar when Delphi 2009 was released with Unicode-only as the default string type, without a switch to revert back to having AnsiString as the default. It was explained that they determined this would be virtually impossible due to the need to have two different versions of the RTL, VCL, and so forth. Allowing ShortString to become the default would require the same thing.

Comment: @KenWhite, Why not post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @ken yes, please make these comments into an answer

Comment: Note that in Delphi 5 or 6, the compiler changed its handling of ShortString operations. A ShortString would be converted to an AnsiString, the operation performed on that temporary value, and the result converted back to ShortString. So even if you could continue to use ShortString, it probably wouldn't be satisfactory. The version of Delphi you're coming from is about 14 years old. Expect to have to change a few things to catch up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$H- is legacy, provided only for backward compatibility. There is no way to force the Delphi XE2 (or any version of Delphi's compiler from D2009 and higher) to not use Unicode as the default string type.

The compiler directive is still there just to prevent old code from breaking when compiled. There was a bit of an uproar when Delphi 2009 was released with Unicode-only as the default string type, without a switch to revert back to having AnsiString as the default. It was explained that they determined this would be virtually impossible due to the need to have two different versions of the RTL, VCL, and so forth. Allowing ShortString to become the default would require the same thing.

You'll need to explicitly change all of your string references to shortstring (or better yet, fix your code to not require them).

Comment: IMO yet another stupid decision from Embarcadero. If the code uses {$H-} there's big chance you'll have to fix it anyway; parsing {$H-} without warnings is just making it harder for the programmer :-/